# eBay SDK AddItem new ProductDetails EAN Requirements CANNOT List Or Revise

Tags: ebay-api

I've asked this question on an [eBay forum](https://forums.developer.ebay.com/questions/12172/problems-using-additem-with-new-productdetails-ean.html) already, but you  have been very helpful, so probably worth posting here too.

Over the past few days I have realised that for many categories in which I sell, EANs are becoming required. I have been trying to update my eBay integration to take this into account, but have run into problems.

The additions to my code provide a workflow, and have problems as follows:

I sell musical instruments and accessories, so let's take a typical example a product "Boss CS-3 Compression Pedal", here's a link to a seller listing it: http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/231547986565

The EAN is **4957054012854**

I want to list this in "**Musical Instruments > Guitars & Basses > Accessories > Effects Pedals**" Category ID for this is: **41410**

So, as I understand it, the first thing I need to know is whether EAN is a requirement for this Category. So, using the eBay .NET SDK I run a post to `GetCategoryFeatures` requesting the following feature IDs:

```
BrandMPNIdentifierEnabled,
EANEnabled,
UPCEnabled,
ISBNIdentifierEnabled
```

The response gives me, amongst other things:

```
EANEnabled: Required,
ISBNEnabled: Disabled,
UPCEnabled: Disabled,
BrandMPNIdentifierEnabled: False
```

This indicates to me that the EAN is a required `ProductDetails` value to include in the `AddItem` post.

So now I need to know if the EAN for this item exists in the eBay Catalogue, so I do a post to `findItemsByProduct` in the `FindingService`. I post to this URL:

http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=[MY-APP-ID]&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByProduct&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-GB&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&REST-PAYLOAD&productId.@type=EAN&productId=4957054012854&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=1

The responses `ack` field is "Failure", which, from what I have gleaned from various internet posts tells me that the item is **not** found in the eBay Catalogue. Why? I don't know, as the listing example I give above shows the EAN in the Item Specifics fields... but anyway...

So, armed with this information, I can find only the advice that I should replaced the EAN value with a value returned from a post to `GeteBayDetails`, the value being found as `ProductIdentifierUnavailableText` which, in my instance (for eBay UK) reads "Does not apply".

Now, I build my item as usual and add the `ProductDetails` value as follows (in VB.net):

```
Dim ProductDetails As New ProductListingDetailsType With {
    .EAN = "Does not apply"
}
```

I also note the requirement for an MPN and add that (it returned an error if not provided)

When I list it, I get a `Failure` response with the following error:

`No product found for ProductListingDetails.<EAN> <Does not apply>.`

If I take away the `ProductDetails` I get:

`Required field, EAN, is missing. Please add EAN to the listing and retry`, so clearly, I do need to provide this information.

**I get exactly the same problem trying to revise a listing.**

I have tried adding the EAN in the `ItemSpecifics` object instead of `ProductDetails`, but that returns the "EAN Missing" error, and have tried alternating between including one, or the other, or both.

So my questions are:

**1:** Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong and how I go about rectifying it, because at the moment I cannot list, or revise items on eBay at all!

**2:** Since most of my suppliers provide a UPC, not an EAN, am I to take it literally that the idetifier to be provided **MUST** be an EAN? Or can I provide the UPC field instead?

Answer (score 1):

Hope this saves someone some time on the addItem and reviseItem call (it took me a while to work out)

I managed to make it work using

```
<ProductListingDetails> 
       <EAN>Does not apply</EAN> 
</ProductListingDetails>
```

Comment: I've already tried that:
`Dim ProductDetails As New ProductListingDetailsType With {
    .EAN = "Does not apply"
}`
I'm posting using the eBay SDK as a Web Reference rather than direct XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can add following into your XML

```
<VariationProductListingDetails>
    <EAN>$EAN</EAN>
</VariationProductListingDetails>
```