# eBay SDK - adding an item - error: No product found for ProductListingDetails. with EAN

Tags: ebay-api, ebay-sdk

I'm trying to add a product to eBay using the API.

Here's a snippet of the code:

```
<Item>
    <Currency>GBP</Currency>
    <Country>GB</Country>
    <ListingDuration>Days_30</ListingDuration>
    <PrimaryCategory>
        <CategoryID>31413</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <Location>GB</Location>
    <StartPrice>42.79</StartPrice>
    <Quantity>10</Quantity>
    <ProductListingDetails>
    <BrandMPN>
      <Brand>Nourkrin</Brand>
      <MPN>NRK-0033</MPN>
    </BrandMPN>
    <UPC>5707725100255</UPC>
    <EAN>5707725100255</EAN>
    <ListIfNoProduct>true</ListIfNoProduct>

    </ProductListingDetails>
```

eBay now requires the Brand, MPN, EAN and UPC however when I add these to my code, I get the error:

```
<ShortMessage>No product found for ProductListingDetails.&lt;EAN&gt; &lt;5707725100255&gt;. </ShortMessage>
```

I think this is because eBay is looking up the EAN in it's product database to see if it exits and is a known product.

If I remove the EAN I get the error:

```
<ShortMessage>No product found for ProductListingDetails.&lt;EAN&gt; &lt;5707725100255&gt;. </ShortMessage>
```

I guess because it's using the UPC, if I remove EAN and UPC I get the error:

```
<ShortMessage>No product found for ProductListingDetails.&lt;BrandMPN&gt; &lt;, NRK0033&gt;. </ShortMessage>
```

and..

```
<LongMessage>Required field, EAN, is missing. Please add EAN to the listing and retry.</LongMessage>
```

I've tried changing EAN and UPC to 'Does not apply'

```
<UPC>Does not apply</UPC>
<EAN>Does not apply</EAN>
```

but I get the error:

```
<ShortMessage>No product found for ProductListingDetails.&lt;UPC&gt; &lt;Does not apply&gt;. </ShortMessage>
```

the `AddItem` template on the sandbox API looks like this:

```
<ISBN> string </ISBN>
<UPC> string </UPC>
<EAN> string </EAN>
<BrandMPN><Brand> string </Brand>
<MPN> string </MPN>
</BrandMPN>
```

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/ebay/AddItem.html

I've also tried removing `<ListIfNoProduct>true</ListIfNoProduct>` but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I looked at this post too:

[eBay SDK AddItem new ProductDetails EAN Requirements CANNOT List Or Revise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30899637/ebay-sdk-additem-new-productdetails-ean-requirements-cannot-list-or-revise)

How can i get this product to list? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had a lot of problems with this, but what worked for me is: if you have UPC number then you have to pass "Does not apply" for EAN (but with EAN then pass empty string to UPC).

Do not pass a number to both fields as this always result in error.

So this should do:

```
<Item>
<Currency>GBP</Currency>
<Country>GB</Country>
<ListingDuration>Days_30</ListingDuration>
<PrimaryCategory>
    <CategoryID>31413</CategoryID>
</PrimaryCategory>
<Location>GB</Location>
<StartPrice>42.79</StartPrice>
<Quantity>10</Quantity>
<ProductListingDetails>
  <BrandMPN>
    <Brand>Nourkrin</Brand>
    <MPN>NRK-0033</MPN>
  </BrandMPN>
  <UPC>Does not apply</UPC>
  <EAN>5707725100255</EAN>
  <ListIfNoProduct>true</ListIfNoProduct>
  ...
</ProductListingDetails>
<ItemSpecifics>
     //add brand and mpn here as well
</ItemSpecifics>
```

Also eBay recommends putting Brand and MPN in `<ItemSpecifics>` tag as well. Sorry I'm working with C# API so I can't give you exact XML representation of it.

Hope this helps.

EDITED:

Checked and `5707725100255` is an EAN number not UPC. Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i tried changing the UPC to Does not apply, however I get the error: No product found for ProductListingDetails.<UPC> <Does not apply>

Comment: Try removing UPC from request.

Comment: ok tried that, it came back with... FailureNo product found for ProductListingDetails.<EAN> <5707725100255>

Comment: Either your EAN is wrong or brand + MPN combo. Also have you added brand + MPN to ItemSpecifics tag?

Comment: yep I added the item specific tags, it's happening for around 8000 items im trying to list on ebay, everything used to work fine until they added in this new rule about EAN/UPC/Brand

Comment: can you post on pastebin or other site full XML for one product?

Comment: I've removed UPC tag and added MPN to ItemSpecifics http://pastebin.com/K65b5Zea p

Comment: I gave it a go, but it came back with an error: FailureNo product found for ProductListingDetails.<EAN> <5707725100255>. No product found for ProductListingDetails.<EAN>  you can check my XML here: http://pastebin.com/mzCCyim2

Comment: I can't spot anything wrong with this. You said you've tried to send "do not apply" for both EAN and UPC so I don't have any more clues. I'd contact eBay directly, maybe there is something wrong on theirs side. Good luck.